# What is the treewidth of a complete bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> What is the [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) of $K_{m,n}$?

Let $l=\min\{m,n\}$ and $k=\lfloor \sqrt{2l}\rfloor$.
A $k$ by $k$ [grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph) is bipartite and contains $\lfloor k^2/2 \rfloor$ vertices in the smaller part and $\lceil k^2/2\rceil$ vertices in the larger part.
Hence $K_{m,n}$ contains a $k$ by $k$ grid as a subgraph, so its treewidth is at least $k = \lfloor \sqrt{2\cdot \min\{m,n\}}\rfloor$.

Is this tight, or if not, is there a more precise expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A graph of treewidth $k$ must be $k$-degenerate. Since $K_{m,n}$ has degeneracy $l=min(m,n)$, the treewidth is at least $l$.

It is at most $l$: let $S$ be the set with $l$ vertices and the other vertices be $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ (say). The tree is $S$ as root and $S \cup \{a_i\}$ as children.

Comment: That is, $tw(K_{m,n})=m+n-\max\{m,n\}=|V|-\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the independence number. In fact, this holds generally for complete multipartite graphs. That is, $tw(K_{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_t})=|V|-\alpha$.